# How does a wavefunction transform under an arbitrary boost?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, group-theory, lie-algebra

How does a wavefunction $\psi$ transforms under an arbitrary boost?

It's easy to find how it transforms under rotation or translation because the corresponding generators form a closed Lie algebra. Exponentiating the generators one can find the group elements and how that act on the wavefunction.

But how to find the boost transformation properties of the wavefunction? Boost generators do not form a closed Lie algebra.

Comment: I think, you mix up something. Generators of transformations form a Lie algebra, the transformation themselves form a Lie group. In particular, spacial rotations form the group SO(3), rotations and boosts together form the group SO(3,1). Concerning the Lie algebra of SO(3,1), see for example here: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/lie-algebra-of-the-so-3-1.570640/

Comment: @Photon The boosts themselves are just some of the generators of $SO(3,1)$.  The full Lorentz group also includes rotation, but the boosts (about different axes) do not close on a subalgebra and so do not exponentiate to a subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you want to boost a *relativistic* $\psi$.
You can always write a pure boost as
$$
\Lambda(\gamma)=R_x(\alpha) R_y(\beta) \Lambda_x(\gamma) R^{-1}_y(\beta) R^{-1}_x(\alpha) 
$$
where $R_y(\alpha)R_x(\beta)$ rotates the direction of your boost to the $\hat x$ axis.

The same strategy works if the boost is Galilean, in which case
$$
L(\gamma)=R_x(\alpha) R_y(\beta) L_x(\gamma) R^{-1}_y(\beta) R^{-1}_x(\alpha) 
$$
where $L_x(\gamma)$ is a pure Galilean boost along $\hat x$.

To see this, you write your pure boost generator along some arbitrary direction as 
$$
\ell= R_x(\alpha) R_y(\beta) \ell_x R^{-1}_y(\beta) R^{-1}_x(\alpha) 
$$
and then exponentiate using $e^{A B A^{-1}}=Ae^B A^{-1}$:
$$
L(\gamma)=e^{\gamma \ell}= R_x(\alpha) R_y(\beta) 
e^{\gamma \ell_x} R^{-1}_y(\beta) R^{-1}_x(\alpha) 
= R_x(\alpha) R_y(\beta) L_x(\gamma) R^{-1}_y(\beta) R^{-1}_x(\alpha) 
$$
with $L_x(\gamma)=e^{\gamma \ell_x}$.

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be a Galilean boost.

Comment: @SRS... Good point but you would do the same, i.e. write the pure boost as $R_x(\alpha)R_y(\beta) L_x(\gamma) R^{-1}_y(\beta)R_x^{-1}(\alpha)$ where $L_x(\gamma)$ is now a pure Galilean boost.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. OP was asking how the wave function (presumably spin 0) transforms under a boost. Specifying $\Lambda$ only tells how a vector transforms. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Boost generators together with those of translations and conformal transformations form a closed Lie algebra. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation

Turn these into operators in te Hilbert space and then act on the wavefunction of choice.

A neat trick is to decompose the wavefunction into plane waves (aka Fourier transformation) The boost on a plane wave is trivially computed, so you can get the desired wavefunction this way:

$$ |\Psi^{\hskip{0.5ex}\prime}\rangle =e^{i\vec V\cdot\vec K}|\Psi\rangle =
\int dp |p\rangle\langle p|e^{i\vec V\cdot\vec K}|\Psi\rangle
$$
and compute the action of the boost on $\langle p|$